# Different result for reading word by word when there is a new line or not

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have problem on that the program cannot read all words in the file if the file part_Q.txt has no new empty line after last visible line.

**part_Q.txt:**

```
NWLR35MQ        649
HCDA93OW        526
```

*Note that there is no empty line after the line "HCDA93OW        526". The text fully finishes right after 526.

**Current output:**

```
word = 'NWLR35MQ'
word = '649'
```

The strange thing is, if I put one more new line after 526, then my program outputs all 4 words, like below.

**Expected output:**

```
word = 'NWLR35MQ'
word = '649'
word = 'HCDA93OW'
word = '526'
```

**Source code:**

```
#!/bin/sh

while read line; do    
    for word in $line; do
        echo "word = '$word'"
    done    
done < part_Q.txt
```

My question is, how can I output all 4 words without having a new empty line at the end of the file, after 526?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]; do
   IFS=' '
   for word in $line; do
      echo "word=$word"
   done
done < file

word=NWLR35MQ
word=649
word=HCDA93OW
word=526
```

Here `|| [[ -n $line ]]` ensures `true` exit status for `while` when `read` fails due to misisng trailing line.